# Tomcat redirection working locally but not on workstations - how can I fix ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have configured tomcat redirection http:\servername:8080\appname to https:\servername:8443\appname but it won't redirect on workstations

the strange thing is I get:

**The connection for this site is not secure**

**servername sent invalid response ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

BUT when I run it locally on the Webserver(servername) it works?

So redirection works? Only on the server.

using https:\servername:8443\appname works just fine so SSL is configured correctly

The same in Chrome and edge